# Wordpress can't connect to database after I change wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, database-connection

I am new to wordpress and have only been working on my macbook (OS Sierra, using MAMP) so far. I had the same issue a few times:
I set up a new WP site locally using the 5 minutes WP installation. That works fine and I can login/logout. However, the wp-config that is created still has the username and passwords as 'root' and 'root'. I tried to change these manually using my WP username/password (those introduced during the 5 minute installation), and then everytime I try to connect to wp-admin or simply load the site I get the error message:
'Error establishing a database connection'
After that, I cannot solve the issue by writing 'root' for username/password in the wp-config anymore. 
I put a long time to set up a site and now cannot access it anymore. Any help is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So the `wp-config` file is not meant to hold your Wordpress credentials. The root/root is what Wordpress uses to connect to the database, and if you want to change it you can find details in the documentation [here](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#q9). So you can't change it from root to your Wordpress credentials because you haven't added a MYSQL user in MAMP with that username and password. Anyways, to get your site back up and running, edit the `wp-config` file back to the following info:

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'root' );
```

Hopefully this helps you better understand the difference between your Wordpress credentials and the MYSQL credentials and the fact that they are not interchangeable. If you have any questions just comment below and I will try to answer them for you!

Cheers and good luck on your site